# How to change the label of a usb?

Tags: linux, bash

I cannot seem to change the label of a USB. I've tried using `dosfslabel` but it doesn't work.

I managed to reformat it to FAT32 the first time, then when I tried to change the label using `sudo dosfslabel /dev/sbl newLabel` it gave me `Got 342 bytes instead of 512 at 0`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/194510/how-to-edit-label-of-usb-drive